# Create SQL query that contains values from Excel column

Tags: sql, excel, vba

So I have an issue, I have a column with `1000+` values, and I need to create a macro that takes all of the values of the cells and pass them to SQL query like `"select * from the table where name in (here is values from column separate with a comma)"`.
Another issue that this query can contain only `500` values, and if the column contains `1000+` values query have to be split like `"select * ...500 values...union all select * ....500 values " and so on`.

Here is some code I already have:

```
Dim wbBook As Workbook
Dim wsSheet As Worksheet
Dim queryString As String
Dim queryString2 As String
Dim queryString3 As String



Set wbBook = ActiveWorkbook
Set wsSheet = wbBook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
queryString = "select * from table where name in ("

With wsSheet

  Range("B2").Select

  Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell) And IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0))

     i = ActiveCell.Value
     queryString = queryString & "'" & i & "',"

     ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Select

  Loop
  wsSheet.Range("N1") = queryString
End With
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What database are you using?  For the 500 records issue, you could use `Select Limit` statement(see [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/select_limit.php)) or `Select Top` statement(see [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/select_top.php)) to get first 500 records.

Comment: I'm using Oracle, so it is impossible to put more than 1000 values in  IN statement

Comment: I dont know `vba` but one alternative from SQL side is that you can create temporary table(_say temp_) and insert these column values into that table. Then you can easily query like `select * from mytable where name in (select myname from temp);`